# How to get values of child objects in an array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
states = [{
    name: telangana,
    cities: [{
      id: 1,
      name: foo
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: joo
    }, {
      id: 3,
      name: goo
    }]
  },
  {
    name: punjab,
    cities: [{
      id: 4,
      name: tyu
    }, {
      id: 5,
      name: ery
    }, {
      id: 6,
      name: doo
    }]
  },
  {
    name: mumbai,
    cities: [{
      id: 7,
      name: eee
    }, {
      id: 8,
      name: qqq
    }, {
      id: 9,
      name: www
    }]
  },
]
```

I want response like `[foo, joo, goo, tyu, ery,doo, eee,qqq,www]`

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Please edit the question to include what you're tried so that we can help you debug it. SO is not here to write code for you.

Comment: `console.log(states.flatMap(({ cities }) => cities.map(({ name }) => name )));` --> please try if that helps.

Comment: @jsN00b, Simpliest one, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just write one line:**

Learn more about [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const states = [{ name: "telangana", cities: [{ id: 1, name: "foo" }, { id: 2, name: "joo" }, { id: 3, name: "goo" }] }, { name: "punjab", cities: [{ id: 4, name: "tyu" }, { id: 5, name: "ery" }, { id: 6, name: "doo" }] }, { name: "mumbai", cities: [{ id: 7, name: "eee" }, { id: 8, name: "qqq" }, { id: 9, name: "www" }] }, ];

const result = states.reduce((acc, { cities }) => [...acc, ...cities.map(({ name }) => name)], []);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const getNames = (data) => {
 const nameArr = [];
 data.forEach((ele) => {
  ele.cities.forEach((ele2) => {
   nameArr.push(ele2.name);
  })
 })
 return nameArr;
}
getNames(states);
```

Try this please!

Answer (score 0):

```
states = [{
    name: "telangana",
    cities: [{
      id: 1,
      name: "foo"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: "joo"
    }, {
      id: 3,
      name: "goo"
    }]
  },
  {
    name: "punjab",
    cities: [{
      id: 4,
      name: "tyu"
    }, {
      id: 5,
      name: "ery"
    }, {
      id: 6,
      name: "doo"
    }]
  },
  {
    name: "mumbai",
    cities: [{
      id: 7,
      name: "eee"
    }, {
      id: 8,
      name: "qqq"
    }, {
      id: 9,
      name: "www"
    }]
  },
]

const wantedArray = []

for(i=0; i < states.length; i++){
    for(j=0; j < states[i].cities.length; j++){
    wantedArray.push(states[i].cities[j].name)
  }
}

console.log(wantedArray)
```

Just give it an empty array, then you loop through the `states` indexes, each index in `states` will have a `cities` array, then you just need to loop it again in that array to get each name of the `cities`. From then, you are using the `push` method that Javascript provides to push it to the empty array.

Here's how I'm doing it in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jebt2k9m/8/), there will have a better way to do this, too.